# Recibir multiples datos selected en datatable con Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, sql, laravel, ajax

Estoy intentando registrar en mi bd multiples select obtenidos del datatable en laravel, pero hasta ahora solo puedo registrar 1 y cuando intente seleccionar varios, solo se registra el ultimo seleccionado

Tengo mi boton que manda ha llamar a la función

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="cotizar" onclick="mod.cotizar();">
                        <i class="fa fa-save"></i>
                        Cotizar Seleccionados
                    </button>
```

Este mod.cotizar tiene la condicional si detecta varios seleccionados

```
mod.cotizar = function (id) {
            if (id != null) {
                ......
            } else {
                var data = mod.tblItems.rows({selected: true}).data();
//Debo validar que selecciono más de 1 para que se active esta funcion
//Si selecciono solo 1 se cumple la primera condicion
                if (data.length > 1) {

                    Swal.fire(
                        {
                            title: "Cotizar",
                            text: "¿Desea cotizar todos estos items?",
                            type: "warning",
                            showCancelButton: true,
                            confirmButtonText: "Si"
                        }).then(function (result) {
                        if (result.value) {
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "{!! route('P0027.cotizar.item',['']) !!}/" + data[0].id,
                                method: 'GET',
                                success: function () {
                                    Swal.fire('', 'Items Cotizados', 'success');
                                    mod.tblItems.ajax.reload();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });


                } else {
                    Swal.fire('', 'Debe seleccionar una registro de la tabla', 'warning');
                }
            }

        };
```

En mi controlador recibo la información y la inserto
Y hasta ahora todo bien pero solo obtiene 1 resultado

```
public function cotizaritem($id)
    {
        try {
        //Verifico que el id obtenido exista
            $item = dt_proyectos_partidas_items::find($id);
            if ($item != null) {
                //Creo un codigo para la cotizacion
                $cor = dt_cotizacion::select(DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
                    ->whereRaw(DB::raw('month(created_at) = month(now())'))
                    ->whereRaw(DB::raw('year(created_at) = year(now())'))
                    ->first();
                $codigo = sprintf("CT%04s%04s", Carbon::now()->format('ym'), $cor->total + 1);
                $cotizacion = new dt_cotizacion();
               .....
                //Guardo la cotizacion
                $cotizacion->save();
                return response()->json(['ok' => true, 'message' => __('Registro almacenado')], 200);
            } else {
                return response()->json(['ok' => false, 'message' => __('Registro no encontrado')], 404);
            }

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return response()->json(['ok' => false, 'message' => $e->getMessage(), 'ln' => $e->getLine(), 'fl' => $e->getFile(), 'c' => $e->getCode()], 404);
        }

    }
```

He intentado usar el foreach, pero creo que no me esta recibiendo todos los id seleccionados y tambien intente con cambiar de GET a POST pero tampoco me funciona

Sera que estoy recibiendo mal los datos? o no los estoy almacenando correctamente?

Comment: Antes de guardar en la tabla verifica lo que estas recibiendo, porque suena a que estas pisando los datos que envías, pensas que envías varios pero solo envías uno a la función que guarda. Revisa que estés recibiendo un array y no otra cosa.

Comment: Existen 2 botones, uno donde envias 1 solo y el otro donde envias varios, por eso al momento de la seleccion valido que se envia 1 o varios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontre la solución!

Para poder enviar un array obtenido de un datatable se debe hacer lo siguiente:
Creamos 2 variables, la primera que recoge los multiple select del datatable y otro para contar esos select

```
 var data12 = mod.tblItems.rows({selected: true}).data();
 var count = mod.tblItems.rows({selected: true}).count();
```

Luego inicializamos un array donde meteremos toda la data

```
var data = [];
```

Luego hacemos un for donde me valide que el numero actual sea menor al contado en los select

```
 for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
//Añadimos un push (una asociación) para cada dato obtenido
                        data.push(i);
//Y para cada dato obtenido le asignamos el id del datatable a cada asociación del array
                       data[i] = data12[i].id;
                    }
```

Luego en el ajax pasamos el array a json

```
 data: JSON.stringify({array: data}),
 dataType:'json',
 contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
```

Y por ultimo dentro del controlador o donde quieran, recibimos el array con foreach

```
 foreach ($request->array as $datas )
```

Y para el que no entendio donde va cada cosa aqui el codigo completo para registrar en un array (que por lo menos me funciono ami) para pasarlo a un controlador en laravel

```
var data12 = mod.tblItems.rows({selected: true}).data();
                var count = mod.tblItems.rows({selected: true}).count();
                if (data12.length > 1) {
                    var data = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                        data.push(i);
                       data[i] = 
                        data12[i].id
                       ;
                    }
                    console.log(data);

                    Swal.fire(
                        {
                            title: "Cotizar",
                            text: "¿Desea cotizar todos estos items?",
                            type: "warning",
                            showCancelButton: true,
                            confirmButtonText: "Si"
                        }).then(function (result) {
                        if (result.value) {
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "{!! route('P0027.cotizar.item1',['']) !!}/" + data12[0].id,
                                method: 'POST',
                                data: JSON.stringify({array: data}),
                                dataType:'json',
                                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',   
                                success: function () {
                                    Swal.fire('', 'Items Cotizados', 'success');
                                    mod.tblItems.ajax.reload();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });


                } else {
                    Swal.fire('', 'Debe seleccionar una registro de la tabla', 'warning');
                }
```